# How can I execute an Ansible role multiple times with different vars from one playbook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that has a role that launches an EC2 instance and allows the user to specify variables about that instance, such as name, node type, instance size, etc.  I want the role to execute multiple times in the same playbook, and with each execution use different vars, so that I can, for example, setup multiple EC2 instances with different names that are otherwise similar.  When I include the role multiple times and change the variables (see example below), only the first instance of the role (in this case, "app-prod-01") in the playbook is executed and the second one is skipped.

How can I execute the role tasks more than once, using different variables for each one, from the same playbook?

The playbook looks like this:

```
production-site-prod.yml:

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vars/prod.yml
    - vars/vpc-cfn.yml
  roles:

    - role: app-aws-prod
      name: "app-prod-01"
      node_type: application
      instance_type: m4.xlarge
      subnet: "{{ subnetapp1 }}"
      elbs:
        - app-public
        - app-private

    - role: app-aws-prod
      name: "app-prod-02"
      node_type: application
      instance_type: m4.xlarge
      subnet: "{{ subnetapp2 }}"
      elbs:
        - app-public
        - app-private
```

And the role app-aws-prod looks like this:

```
main.yml

- name: validate arguments 1/2 
  assert:
    that:
      - prefix == ""
      - suffixes == [""]
  when: name != ""

- name: validate arguments 2/2
  assert:
    that:
      - prefix != ""
      - suffixes != [""]
  when: name == ""

- include: sg.yml
- include: iam.yml
- include: ec2-instance.yml
```

My ec2-instance.yml looks like this:

```
ec2-instance.yml

- name: launch instances
  ec2:
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    group_id: "{{ sgcommon }},{{ project_sg.group_id }},{{ app_sg.group_id }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    image: "{{ image_ami }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet }}"
    assign_public_ip: no
    exact_count: 1
    ebs_optimized: yes
    instance_profile_name: "{{ iam.stack_outputs.iamprofile }}"
    count_tag:
        Name: "{{ name }}{{ prefix }}{{ item }}"
        Environment: "{{ environment_name }}"
        Project: "{{ project_name }}"
        node_type: "{{ node_type }}"
    instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ name }}{{ prefix }}{{ item }}"
        Environment: "{{ environment_name }}"
        Project: "{{ project_name }}"
        node_type: "{{ node_type }}"
    wait: yes
    wait_timeout: 300
  with_items: "{{ suffixes }}"
  register: ec2_instance

- include: volume.yml
  vars:
    volume_type: 'temp'
    volume_size: "{{ temp_volume_size }}"
    device_name: '/dev/xvdf'
    volume_retention: 10 
- include: route53.yml 
- include: elb.yml
```

When I use the `--list-tags` flag on `ansible-playbook` I see the output I expect, each role has the same set of tasks and they are displayed:

[ec2-user@fob production]$ ansible-playbook --list-tasks production-site-prod.yml

```
playbook: production-site-prod.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost        TAGS: []
    tasks:
      app-aws-prod : validate arguments 1/2    TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : validate arguments 2/2    TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : project security group access from common TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : app node security group access from office       TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : app application security group access from ELBs  TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : get db security group name        TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : db security group access from project security group      TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : get cache security group name     TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : cache security group access from project security group   TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : add iam role and managed policies TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : launch instances  TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : attach volume     TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : tag volume        TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : create dns record TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : attach instance to elb    TAGS: []
      debug     TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : validate arguments 1/2    TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : validate arguments 2/2    TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : project security group access from common TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : app node security group access from office       TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : app application security group access from ELBs  TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : get db security group name        TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : db security group access from project security group      TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : get cache security group name     TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : cache security group access from project security group   TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : add iam role and managed policies TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : launch instances  TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : attach volume     TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : tag volume        TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : create dns record TAGS: []
      app-aws-prod : attach instance to elb    TAGS: []
      debug     TAGS: []
```

`ansible-playbook` output:

```
[ec2-user@fob ansible]$ ansible-playbook ./projects/app/production/production-site-prod.yml -v
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [app-aws-prod : validate arguments 1/2] **********************************
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "msg": "all assertions passed"}

TASK [app-aws-prod : validate arguments 2/2] **********************************
skipping: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed", "skipped": true}

TASK [app-aws-prod : project security group access from common] ***************
[u'us-east-1/prod-vpc/output/sgcommon']
[u'us-east-1/prod-vpc/output/vpcId']
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "group_id": "sg-3ddf0b47"}

TASK [app-aws-prod : app node security group access from office] *************
[u'us-east-1/prod-vpc/output/vpcId']
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "group_id": "sg-1109a26b"}

TASK [app-aws-prod : app application security group access from ELBs] ********
[u'us-east-1/prod-app-public-elb/output/elbsg']
[u'us-east-1/prod-vpc/output/vpcId']
ok: [localhost] => (item=app-public) => {"changed": false, "group_id": "sg-1109a26b", "item": "app-public"}
[u'us-east-1/prod-app-private-elb/output/elbsg']
[u'us-east-1/prod-vpc/output/vpcId']
ok: [localhost] => (item=app-private) => {"changed": false, "group_id": "sg-1109a26b", "item": "app-private"}

TASK [app-aws-prod : get db security group name] ******************************
[u'us-east-1/prod-bash-prod/output/dbsg']
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "cmd": "aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region us-east-1 --group-id sg-4c5ff136 --query 'SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName}'", "delta": "0:00:00.610211", "end": "2016-08-30 16:04:38.280314", "rc": 0, "start": "2016-08-30 16:04:37.670103", "stderr": "", "stdout": "[\n    {\n        \"Name\": \"prod-bash-prod-dbSg-8HW8N2N5XBO6\"\n    }\n]", "stdout_lines": ["[", "    {", "        \"Name\": \"prod-bash-prod-dbSg-8HW8N2N5XBO6\"", "    }", "]"], "warnings": []}

TASK [app-aws-prod : db security group access from project security group] ****
[u'us-east-1/prod-vpc/output/vpcId']
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "group_id": "sg-4c5ff136"}

TASK [app-aws-prod : get cache security group name] ***************************
[u'us-east-1/prod-c1/output/cachesg']
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "cmd": "aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region us-east-1 --group-id sg-8962ccf3 --query 'SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName}'", "delta": "0:00:00.606839", "end": "2016-08-30 16:04:39.781701", "rc": 0, "start": "2016-08-30 16:04:39.174862", "stderr": "", "stdout": "[\n    {\n        \"Name\": \"prod-c1-cacheSg-KNT3HMZ1ER2H\"\n    }\n]", "stdout_lines": ["[", "    {", "        \"Name\": \"prod-c1-cacheSg-KNT3HMZ1ER2H\"", "    }", "]"], "warnings": []}

TASK [app-aws-prod : cache security group access from project security group] *
[u'us-east-1/prod-vpc/output/vpcId']
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "group_id": "sg-8962ccf3"}

TASK [app-aws-prod : add iam role and managed policies] ***********************
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "output": "Stack is already up-to-date.", "stack_outputs": {"iamprofile": "prod-app-application-iam-iamprofile-19MNPICSTUPKD", "iamrole": "prod-app-application-iam-iamrole-1A7BZFODEXCBA"}, "stack_resources": [{"last_updated_time": null, "logical_resource_id": "iamprofile", "physical_resource_id": "prod-app-application-iam-iamprofile-19MNPICSTUPKD", "resource_type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile", "status": "CREATE_COMPLETE", "status_reason": null}, {"last_updated_time": null, "logical_resource_id": "iamrole", "physical_resource_id": "prod-app-application-iam-iamrole-1A7BZFODEXCBA", "resource_type": "AWS::IAM::Role", "status": "CREATE_COMPLETE", "status_reason": null}, {"last_updated_time": null, "logical_resource_id": "s3DeployAccess", "physical_resource_id": "arn:aws:iam::498429009301:policy/prod-app-application-iam-s3DeployAccess-1A38BHBPXN2AI", "resource_type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy", "status": "CREATE_COMPLETE", "status_reason": null}]}

TASK [app-aws-prod : launch instances] ****************************************
[u'us-east-1/prod-vpc/output/subnetapp1']
[u'us-east-1/prod-vpc/output/sgcommon']
ok: [localhost] => (item=) => {"changed": false, "instance_ids": null, "instances": [], "item": "", "tagged_instances": [{"ami_launch_index": "0", "architecture": "x86_64", "block_device_mapping": {"/dev/xvda": {"delete_on_termination": true, "status": "attached", "volume_id": "vol-655aefc2"}, "/dev/xvdf": {"delete_on_termination": false, "status": "attached", "volume_id": "vol-2b45f08c"}}, "dns_name": "", "ebs_optimized": true, "groups": {"sg-1109a26b": "prod-app-application-sg", "sg-3ddf0b47": "prod-app-sg", "sg-c85791b2": "prod-vpc-sgcommon-XEW9RXT290FG"}, "hypervisor": "xen", "id": "i-76ce6a77", "image_id": "ami-60b6c60a", "instance_type": "m4.xlarge", "kernel": null, "key_name": "production", "launch_time": "2016-08-25T19:20:46.000Z", "placement": "us-east-1a", "private_dns_name": "ip-10-70-10-50.ec2.internal", "private_ip": "10.70.10.50", "public_dns_name": "", "public_ip": null, "ramdisk": null, "region": "us-east-1", "root_device_name": "/dev/xvda", "root_device_type": "ebs", "state": "running", "state_code": 16, "tags": {"Environment": "prod", "Name": "app-prod-01", "Project": "app", "node_type": "application"}, "tenancy": "default", "virtualization_type": "hvm"}]}

TASK [app-aws-prod : attach volume] *******************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, u'instances': [], '_ansible_item_result': True, u'instance_ids': None, 'item': u'', u'tagged_instances': [{u'kernel': None, u'root_device_type': u'ebs', u'private_dns_name': u'ip-10-70-10-50.ec2.internal', u'public_ip': None, u'private_ip': u'10.70.10.50', u'id': u'i-76ce6a77', u'ebs_optimized': True, u'state': u'running', u'virtualization_type': u'hvm', u'architecture': u'x86_64', u'ramdisk': None, u'block_device_mapping': {u'/dev/xvda': {u'status': u'attached', u'delete_on_termination': True, u'volume_id': u'vol-655aefc2'}, u'/dev/xvdf': {u'status': u'attached', u'delete_on_termination': False, u'volume_id': u'vol-2b45f08c'}}, u'key_name': u'production', u'image_id': u'ami-60b6c60a', u'tenancy': u'default', u'groups': {u'sg-1109a26b': u'prod-app-application-sg', u'sg-3ddf0b47': u'prod-app-sg', u'sg-c85791b2': u'prod-vpc-sgcommon-XEW9RXT290FG'}, u'public_dns_name': u'', u'state_code': 16, u'tags': {u'Project': u'app', u'Environment': u'prod', u'node_type': u'application', u'Name': u'app-prod-01'}, u'placement': u'us-east-1a', u'ami_launch_index': u'0', u'dns_name': u'', u'region': u'us-east-1', u'launch_time': u'2016-08-25T19:20:46.000Z', u'instance_type': u'm4.xlarge', u'root_device_name': u'/dev/xvda', u'hypervisor': u'xen'}], 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ec2', u'module_args': {u'kernel': None, u'image': u'ami-60b6c60a', u'monitoring': False, u'user_data': None, u'count_tag': u"{'Environment': 'prod', 'Project': 'app', 'node_type': 'application', 'Name': 'app-prod-01'}", u'private_ip': None, u'spot_type': u'one-time', u'ec2_url': None, u'id': None, u'source_dest_check': True, u'aws_secret_key': None, u'spot_wait_timeout': u'600', u'group': None, u'zone': None, u'exact_count': 1, u'ebs_optimized': True, u'state': u'present', u'placement_group': None, u'spot_launch_group': None, u'ramdisk': None, u'key_name': u'production', u'vpc_subnet_id': u'subnet-15c8c44d', u'instance_ids': None, u'wait_timeout': u'300', u'profile': None, u'assign_public_ip': False, u'spot_price': None, u'wait': True, u'count': 1, u'aws_access_key': None, u'instance_profile_name': u'prod-app-application-iam-iamprofile-19MNPICSTUPKD', u'security_token': None, u'region': u'us-east-1', u'network_interfaces': None, u'termination_protection': False, u'instance_type': u'm4.xlarge', u'tenancy': u'default', u'volumes': None, u'instance_tags': {u'Environment': u'prod', u'Project': u'app', u'node_type': u'application', u'Name': u'app-prod-01'}, u'group_id': [u'sg-c85791b2', u'sg-3ddf0b47', u'sg-1109a26b'], u'validate_certs': True}}}) => {"changed": false, "device": "/dev/xvdf", "item": {"changed": false, "instance_ids": null, "instances": [], "invocation": {"module_args": {"assign_public_ip": false, "aws_access_key": null, "aws_secret_key": null, "count": 1, "count_tag": "{'Environment': 'prod', 'Project': 'app', 'node_type': 'application', 'Name': 'app-prod-01'}", "ebs_optimized": true, "ec2_url": null, "exact_count": 1, "group": null, "group_id": ["sg-c85791b2", "sg-3ddf0b47", "sg-1109a26b"], "id": null, "image": "ami-60b6c60a", "instance_ids": null, "instance_profile_name": "prod-app-application-iam-iamprofile-19MNPICSTUPKD", "instance_tags": {"Environment": "prod", "Name": "app-prod-01", "Project": "app", "node_type": "application"}, "instance_type": "m4.xlarge", "kernel": null, "key_name": "production", "monitoring": false, "network_interfaces": null, "placement_group": null, "private_ip": null, "profile": null, "ramdisk": null, "region": "us-east-1", "security_token": null, "source_dest_check": true, "spot_launch_group": null, "spot_price": null, "spot_type": "one-time", "spot_wait_timeout": "600", "state": "present", "tenancy": "default", "termination_protection": false, "user_data": null, "validate_certs": true, "volumes": null, "vpc_subnet_id": "subnet-15c8c44d", "wait": true, "wait_timeout": "300", "zone": null}, "module_name": "ec2"}, "item": "", "tagged_instances": [{"ami_launch_index": "0", "architecture": "x86_64", "block_device_mapping": {"/dev/xvda": {"delete_on_termination": true, "status": "attached", "volume_id": "vol-655aefc2"}, "/dev/xvdf": {"delete_on_termination": false, "status": "attached", "volume_id": "vol-2b45f08c"}}, "dns_name": "", "ebs_optimized": true, "groups": {"sg-1109a26b": "prod-app-application-sg", "sg-3ddf0b47": "prod-app-sg", "sg-c85791b2": "prod-vpc-sgcommon-XEW9RXT290FG"}, "hypervisor": "xen", "id": "i-76ce6a77", "image_id": "ami-60b6c60a", "instance_type": "m4.xlarge", "kernel": null, "key_name": "production", "launch_time": "2016-08-25T19:20:46.000Z", "placement": "us-east-1a", "private_dns_name": "ip-10-70-10-50.ec2.internal", "private_ip": "10.70.10.50", "public_dns_name": "", "public_ip": null, "ramdisk": null, "region": "us-east-1", "root_device_name": "/dev/xvda", "root_device_type": "ebs", "state": "running", "state_code": 16, "tags": {"Environment": "prod", "Name": "app-prod-01", "Project": "app", "node_type": "application"}, "tenancy": "default", "virtualization_type": "hvm"}]}, "msg": "Volume mapping for /dev/xvdf already exists on instance i-76ce6a77", "volume_id": "vol-2b45f08c"}

TASK [app-aws-prod : tag volume] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=(0, {u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': {u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'item': u'', '_ansible_item_result': True, u'instance_ids': None, u'instances': [], u'tagged_instances': [{u'kernel': None, u'root_device_type': u'ebs', u'private_dns_name': u'ip-10-70-10-50.ec2.internal', u'public_ip': None, u'private_ip': u'10.70.10.50', u'id': u'i-76ce6a77', u'ebs_optimized': True, u'state': u'running', u'virtualization_type': u'hvm', u'architecture': u'x86_64', u'ramdisk': None, u'block_device_mapping': {u'/dev/xvda': {u'status': u'attached', u'delete_on_termination': True, u'volume_id': u'vol-655aefc2'}, u'/dev/xvdf': {u'status': u'attached', u'delete_on_termination': False, u'volume_id': u'vol-2b45f08c'}}, u'key_name': u'production', u'image_id': u'ami-60b6c60a', u'tenancy': u'default', u'groups': {u'sg-1109a26b': u'prod-app-application-sg', u'sg-3ddf0b47': u'prod-app-sg', u'sg-c85791b2': u'prod-vpc-sgcommon-XEW9RXT290FG'}, u'public_dns_name': u'', u'state_code': 16, u'tags': {u'Project': u'app', u'Environment': u'prod', u'node_type': u'application', u'Name': u'app-prod-01'}, u'placement': u'us-east-1a', u'ami_launch_index': u'0', u'dns_name': u'', u'region': u'us-east-1', u'launch_time': u'2016-08-25T19:20:46.000Z', u'instance_type': u'm4.xlarge', u'root_device_name': u'/dev/xvda', u'hypervisor': u'xen'}], 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ec2', u'module_args': {u'kernel': None, u'image': u'ami-60b6c60a', u'user_data': None, u'count_tag': u"{'Environment': 'prod', 'Project': 'app', 'node_type': 'application', 'Name': 'app-prod-01'}", u'private_ip': None, u'spot_type': u'one-time', u'ec2_url': None, u'id': None, u'source_dest_check': True, u'aws_secret_key': None, u'spot_wait_timeout': u'600', u'monitoring': False, u'zone': None, u'exact_count': 1, u'ebs_optimized': True, u'state': u'present', u'placement_group': None, u'spot_launch_group': None, u'ramdisk': None, u'key_name': u'production', u'vpc_subnet_id': u'subnet-15c8c44d', u'instance_ids': None, u'spot_price': None, u'wait_timeout': u'300', u'profile': None, u'assign_public_ip': False, u'group': None, u'wait': True, u'count': 1, u'aws_access_key': None, u'instance_profile_name': u'prod-app-application-iam-iamprofile-19MNPICSTUPKD', u'security_token': None, u'region': u'us-east-1', u'network_interfaces': None, u'termination_protection': False, u'instance_type': u'm4.xlarge', u'tenancy': u'default', u'volumes': None, u'instance_tags': {u'Environment': u'prod', u'Project': u'app', u'node_type': u'application', u'Name': u'app-prod-01'}, u'group_id': [u'sg-c85791b2', u'sg-3ddf0b47', u'sg-1109a26b'], u'validate_certs': True}}}, u'device': u'/dev/xvdf', u'volume_id': u'vol-2b45f08c', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ec2_vol', u'module_args': {u'aws_secret_key': None, u'profile': None, u'aws_access_key': None, u'name': None, u'zone': None, u'instance': u'i-76ce6a77', u'encrypted': False, u'region': u'us-east-1', u'volume_type': u'gp2', u'device_name': u'/dev/xvdf', u'volume_size': u'100', u'state': u'present', u'iops': None, u'snapshot': None, u'ec2_url': None, u'id': None, u'security_token': None, u'validate_certs': True, u'delete_on_termination': False}}, u'msg': u'Volume mapping for /dev/xvdf already exists on instance i-76ce6a77'})) => {"changed": false, "item": [0, {"_ansible_item_result": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "changed": false, "device": "/dev/xvdf", "invocation": {"module_args": {"aws_access_key": null, "aws_secret_key": null, "delete_on_termination": false, "device_name": "/dev/xvdf", "ec2_url": null, "encrypted": false, "id": null, "instance": "i-76ce6a77", "iops": null, "name": null, "profile": null, "region": "us-east-1", "security_token": null, "snapshot": null, "state": "present", "validate_certs": true, "volume_size": "100", "volume_type": "gp2", "zone": null}, "module_name": "ec2_vol"}, "item": {"_ansible_item_result": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "changed": false, "instance_ids": null, "instances": [], "invocation": {"module_args": {"assign_public_ip": false, "aws_access_key": null, "aws_secret_key": null, "count": 1, "count_tag": "{'Environment': 'prod', 'Project': 'app', 'node_type': 'application', 'Name': 'app-prod-01'}", "ebs_optimized": true, "ec2_url": null, "exact_count": 1, "group": null, "group_id": ["sg-c85791b2", "sg-3ddf0b47", "sg-1109a26b"], "id": null, "image": "ami-60b6c60a", "instance_ids": null, "instance_profile_name": "prod-app-application-iam-iamprofile-19MNPICSTUPKD", "instance_tags": {"Environment": "prod", "Name": "app-prod-01", "Project": "app", "node_type": "application"}, "instance_type": "m4.xlarge", "kernel": null, "key_name": "production", "monitoring": false, "network_interfaces": null, "placement_group": null, "private_ip": null, "profile": null, "ramdisk": null, "region": "us-east-1", "security_token": null, "source_dest_check": true, "spot_launch_group": null, "spot_price": null, "spot_type": "one-time", "spot_wait_timeout": "600", "state": "present", "tenancy": "default", "termination_protection": false, "user_data": null, "validate_certs": true, "volumes": null, "vpc_subnet_id": "subnet-15c8c44d", "wait": true, "wait_timeout": "300", "zone": null}, "module_name": "ec2"}, "item": "", "tagged_instances": [{"ami_launch_index": "0", "architecture": "x86_64", "block_device_mapping": {"/dev/xvda": {"delete_on_termination": true, "status": "attached", "volume_id": "vol-655aefc2"}, "/dev/xvdf": {"delete_on_termination": false, "status": "attached", "volume_id": "vol-2b45f08c"}}, "dns_name": "", "ebs_optimized": true, "groups": {"sg-1109a26b": "prod-app-application-sg", "sg-3ddf0b47": "prod-app-sg", "sg-c85791b2": "prod-vpc-sgcommon-XEW9RXT290FG"}, "hypervisor": "xen", "id": "i-76ce6a77", "image_id": "ami-60b6c60a", "instance_type": "m4.xlarge", "kernel": null, "key_name": "production", "launch_time": "2016-08-25T19:20:46.000Z", "placement": "us-east-1a", "private_dns_name": "ip-10-70-10-50.ec2.internal", "private_ip": "10.70.10.50", "public_dns_name": "", "public_ip": null, "ramdisk": null, "region": "us-east-1", "root_device_name": "/dev/xvda", "root_device_type": "ebs", "state": "running", "state_code": 16, "tags": {"Environment": "prod", "Name": "app-prod-01", "Project": "app", "node_type": "application"}, "tenancy": "default", "virtualization_type": "hvm"}]}, "msg": "Volume mapping for /dev/xvdf already exists on instance i-76ce6a77", "volume_id": "vol-2b45f08c"}], "msg": "Tags already exists in vol-2b45f08c."}

TASK [app-aws-prod : create dns record] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=(0, {u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, u'instances': [], '_ansible_item_result': True, u'instance_ids': None, 'item': u'', u'tagged_instances': [{u'kernel': None, u'root_device_type': u'ebs', u'private_dns_name': u'ip-10-70-10-50.ec2.internal', u'public_ip': None, u'private_ip': u'10.70.10.50', u'id': u'i-76ce6a77', u'ebs_optimized': True, u'state': u'running', u'virtualization_type': u'hvm', u'architecture': u'x86_64', u'ramdisk': None, u'block_device_mapping': {u'/dev/xvda': {u'status': u'attached', u'delete_on_termination': True, u'volume_id': u'vol-655aefc2'}, u'/dev/xvdf': {u'status': u'attached', u'delete_on_termination': False, u'volume_id': u'vol-2b45f08c'}}, u'key_name': u'production', u'image_id': u'ami-60b6c60a', u'tenancy': u'default', u'groups': {u'sg-1109a26b': u'prod-app-application-sg', u'sg-3ddf0b47': u'prod-app-sg', u'sg-c85791b2': u'prod-vpc-sgcommon-XEW9RXT290FG'}, u'public_dns_name': u'', u'state_code': 16, u'tags': {u'Project': u'app', u'Environment': u'prod', u'node_type': u'application', u'Name': u'app-prod-01'}, u'placement': u'us-east-1a', u'ami_launch_index': u'0', u'dns_name': u'', u'region': u'us-east-1', u'launch_time': u'2016-08-25T19:20:46.000Z', u'instance_type': u'm4.xlarge', u'root_device_name': u'/dev/xvda', u'hypervisor': u'xen'}], 'invocation': {'module_name': u'ec2', u'module_args': {u'kernel': None, u'image': u'ami-60b6c60a', u'monitoring': False, u'user_data': None, u'count_tag': u"{'Environment': 'prod', 'Project': 'app', 'node_type': 'application', 'Name': 'app-prod-01'}", u'private_ip': None, u'spot_type': u'one-time', u'ec2_url': None, u'id': None, u'source_dest_check': True, u'aws_secret_key': None, u'spot_wait_timeout': u'600', u'group': None, u'zone': None, u'exact_count': 1, u'ebs_optimized': True, u'state': u'present', u'placement_group': None, u'spot_launch_group': None, u'ramdisk': None, u'key_name': u'production', u'vpc_subnet_id': u'subnet-15c8c44d', u'instance_ids': None, u'wait_timeout': u'300', u'profile': None, u'assign_public_ip': False, u'spot_price': None, u'wait': True, u'count': 1, u'aws_access_key': None, u'instance_profile_name': u'prod-app-application-iam-iamprofile-19MNPICSTUPKD', u'security_token': None, u'region': u'us-east-1', u'network_interfaces': None, u'termination_protection': False, u'instance_type': u'm4.xlarge', u'tenancy': u'default', u'volumes': None, u'instance_tags': {u'Environment': u'prod', u'Project': u'app', u'node_type': u'application', u'Name': u'app-prod-01'}, u'group_id': [u'sg-c85791b2', u'sg-3ddf0b47', u'sg-1109a26b'], u'validate_certs': True}}})) => {"changed": false, "item": [0, {"_ansible_item_result": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "changed": false, "instance_ids": null, "instances": [], "invocation": {"module_args": {"assign_public_ip": false, "aws_access_key": null, "aws_secret_key": null, "count": 1, "count_tag": "{'Environment': 'prod', 'Project': 'app', 'node_type': 'application', 'Name': 'app-prod-01'}", "ebs_optimized": true, "ec2_url": null, "exact_count": 1, "group": null, "group_id": ["sg-c85791b2", "sg-3ddf0b47", "sg-1109a26b"], "id": null, "image": "ami-60b6c60a", "instance_ids": null, "instance_profile_name": "prod-app-application-iam-iamprofile-19MNPICSTUPKD", "instance_tags": {"Environment": "prod", "Name": "app-prod-01", "Project": "app", "node_type": "application"}, "instance_type": "m4.xlarge", "kernel": null, "key_name": "production", "monitoring": false, "network_interfaces": null, "placement_group": null, "private_ip": null, "profile": null, "ramdisk": null, "region": "us-east-1", "security_token": null, "source_dest_check": true, "spot_launch_group": null, "spot_price": null, "spot_type": "one-time", "spot_wait_timeout": "600", "state": "present", "tenancy": "default", "termination_protection": false, "user_data": null, "validate_certs": true, "volumes": null, "vpc_subnet_id": "subnet-15c8c44d", "wait": true, "wait_timeout": "300", "zone": null}, "module_name": "ec2"}, "item": "", "tagged_instances": [{"ami_launch_index": "0", "architecture": "x86_64", "block_device_mapping": {"/dev/xvda": {"delete_on_termination": true, "status": "attached", "volume_id": "vol-655aefc2"}, "/dev/xvdf": {"delete_on_termination": false, "status": "attached", "volume_id": "vol-2b45f08c"}}, "dns_name": "", "ebs_optimized": true, "groups": {"sg-1109a26b": "prod-app-application-sg", "sg-3ddf0b47": "prod-app-sg", "sg-c85791b2": "prod-vpc-sgcommon-XEW9RXT290FG"}, "hypervisor": "xen", "id": "i-76ce6a77", "image_id": "ami-60b6c60a", "instance_type": "m4.xlarge", "kernel": null, "key_name": "production", "launch_time": "2016-08-25T19:20:46.000Z", "placement": "us-east-1a", "private_dns_name": "ip-10-70-10-50.ec2.internal", "private_ip": "10.70.10.50", "public_dns_name": "", "public_ip": null, "ramdisk": null, "region": "us-east-1", "root_device_name": "/dev/xvda", "root_device_type": "ebs", "state": "running", "state_code": 16, "tags": {"Environment": "prod", "Name": "app-prod-01", "Project": "app", "node_type": "application"}, "tenancy": "default", "virtualization_type": "hvm"}]}]}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=13   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

[ec2-user@fob ansible]$
```

Comment: Please add output of `ansible-playbook` when second role is skipped. In general, this syntax should work fine.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov The output of `ansible-playbook` doesn't indicate any issues;  it stops after the last task for the first role is done.  I'll add it to the question anyway.

Comment: In question you have `production-site.yml` and in output `production-site-prod.yml`. Is this ok? Check `ansible-playbook --list-tasks ./projects/app/production/production-site-prod.yml`

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Sorry, transposition errors.  They are named the same.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Maybe this is a bug in ansible?  When I use `--list-tasks`, it lists the tasks correctly for each instance of the role.

Comment: Not sure what version of Ansible you're using, but this works fine for me on 2.1.1 and devel...

Comment: @MattDavis 2.1.1.0, haven't figured out what's going wrong here.  I just got rid of the first role in the playbook and ran the second because I don't have time to figure it out.  :(

Comment: @LegendaryDude does the role happen to have some role dependencies defined in `meta/main.yml`?

Comment: @StrahinjaKustudic There are no dependencies defined for that particular role in `meta/main.yml`, and I even added `allow_duplicates: yes` to `meta/main.yml`.  For what it's worth, `meta/main.yml` didn't exist for this role until I created it specifically to add the `allow_duplicates: yes` setting.

Comment: I can recommend you to run playbook with `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1` and check what's wrong. Because if everything is OK, you shouldn't get `NO MORE HOSTS LEFT` message.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov `NO MORE HOSTS LEFT` message comes from the fact that this playbook specifies only `localhost` and uses the locally installed AWS API to execute.  Roles and hosts are not the same in this case.  As for running with debug on, already tried that and didn't get any useful information.

Comment: If you look into `NO MORE HOSTS LEFT` thing closely, you'll notice that it is printed by `v2_playbook_on_no_hosts_remaining` callback, which in turn triggered only when some error occurs and all hosts (in your example the only one – localhost) are marked as failed or unreachable... So I think there should be some useful info in debug stream after `create dns record` task.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov There is an error which I have not included here because I didn't think it relevant -- the last task (which is not in the `ansible-playbook` output) is to attach the EC2 instance to an ELB, which fails because at the point in time which this is done, the EC2 instance does not pass the required health check to return a success response.  Do you think the failure of a single task in the first role is the cause of the second role to not run at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer, based on additional info from comments:

> There is an error which I have not included here because I didn't think it relevant -- the last task (which is not in the ansible-playbook output) is to attach the EC2 instance to an ELB, which fails...

If any task on the host fails (unless you specify `ignore_errors: yes`), ansible mark this host as failed and stop execution of remaining tasks.

So, you have only one host `localhost` and when it is marked as failed, execution of playbook stops.